# Rails 3: How to add/remove a group of fields using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm trying to figure out how to add and remove a group of fields in my Rails 3 app using Jquery. I got the jquery script to work with plain html, which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/beehive/ABvFH/1/

However, I can't figure out how to translate this to Rails 3. More specifically, what do I replace "formfield" with in the application.js file for this to work?

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        var x = $('#uploadform');
        var i = $('#uploadform ul').size() + 1;

        $('#addmore').live('click', function() {
            if ($(".item", x).length < 9) {
                $('<ul class="item" class="field">formfield ' + i + ' <a href="#" id="remfields">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(x);
                i++;
            }
            return false;
        });

        $('#remfields').live('click', function() {
            if (i > 2) {
                $(this).parents('ul').remove();
                i--;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });​


});
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@upload) do |f| %>
  <% if @upload.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@upload.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this upload from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @upload.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <h2><a href="#" id="addmore">Add More Fields</a></h2>
  <div id="uploadform">
    <ul class="field">
      <li>
        <%= f.label :title %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= f.label :genre %><br />
        <%= f.collection_select :genre, Upload::GENRES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= f.label :category %><br />
        <%= f.collection_select :category, Upload::CATEGORIES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= f.label :age %><br />
        <%= f.collection_select :age, Upload::AGES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do to get it to work is comment `$(function() {`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$(function() {
        var x = $('#uploadform');
        var i = $('#uploadform ul').size() + 1;

        $('#addmore').live('click', function() {
            if ($(".item", x).length < 9) {
                $('<ul class="item" class="field">formfield ' + i + ' <a href="#" id="remfields">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(x);
                i++;
            }
            return false;
        });

        $('#remfields').live('click', function() {
            if (i > 2) {
                $(this).parents('ul').remove();
                i--;
            }
            return false;
        });
    //});​


});
```

**Edit:**

What do you mean insert them?

To access the elements you can loop through them with

```
    $('#uploadform > ul').each(function(index) {
        alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
    });
```

Notice your generated HTML.  You are creating ul (unordered list) for each li (list item).  you may want to fix that to only append list items.

Comment: haha...that definitely helps. How do I insert all the #uploadform fields (from form.html.erb) into the application.js file, where "formfield" currently is?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to allow user to add many uploads before submit form.
In that case I'm using rails [nested attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).

Here is example. **Order has many Photos**

Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :dependent=>:destroy, :inverse_of=>:order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy=>true,:reject_if=> :all_blank
end
```

Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Order form view:

```
<%= form_for @order, :html => {:autocomplete => :off, :multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <h3>Order photos</h3>
        <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
        <%= render :partial=>'photo_form', :object=> photo, :as => :f %>
        <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Add photo', new_photo_path, :remote=>true, :id=>'add_photo'  %>
    <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

photo_form partial:

```
<fieldset class="photo" data-status="<%= f.object.persisted? ? 'db':'new' %>">
   <% if f.object.persisted? %>
      <div class="field">
    <label>Photo:</label><br />
    <%= link_to f.object.photo.url, :target=>'_blank' do %><%= image_tag f.object.photo.url(:mini) %><% end %>
      </div>
   <% else %>
      <%= f.label :photo
      <%= f.file_field :photo %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy, :class=>'delete' %>
</fieldset>
```

Now in your controller you need 3 actions to edit order with photos: edit, update, add_photo(ajax action when user click add photo link):

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Action responsible for updating existing order record
  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
       redirect_to @order, :notice=>'Order updated'
    else
       render :action => "edit" #save error, display order form with errors
    end
  end

  # Action responsible for creating nested form for order photo
  def new_photo
    #nothing just renders 'new_photo.js.erb'
  end
end
```

new_photo.js.erb:

```
$object=$("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "photo_form", :locals=>{
    :f=>FormBuilder.new("order[photos_attributes][#{rand(400000)}]",Photo.new(),self,{},proc {})
}) ) %>").hide();  //generates new photo view
$object.insertBefore("a#add_photo").slideDown(500);
```

This is just example, but you shouldn't have problem to adopt this in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually was using a nested form for this, but I had to ditch it because it lost all functionality when I incorporated it into my multi-step form.